# Get all objects with the same constructor as integer?

Tags: java, constructor

I got the following class:

```
public class Possibility {


    private String name;

    public Possibility(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

If I now have many classes that extend "Possibility", how can I find how many instances exist of classes that extend Possibility?

Comment: What relevance is the class?

Comment: what do u mean with that?

Comment: On Unix I’d grep for `extends Possibility`. It may not give an accurate count since the extends clause might be wrapped over two lines or also appear in comments or string literals. In Eclipse I’d select the class name and hit F4 to see the entire inheritance tree.

Comment: Are all the classes that extend the class in question all in the same class path?

Comment: yes they are  all

Comment: I rollback the title because it is not necessary to indicate the question status explicitly in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static field as a counter in Possibility class and use it to increment as the objects are created. This is more efficient and secure than using reflection.

```
package so;

public class Possibility {
    private static int counter = 0;

    private String name;

    public Possibility(String name) {
        counter += 1;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Possibility1 p1 = new Possibility1("p1");
        Possibility2 p2 = new Possibility2("p2");

        System.out.println(Possibility.counter);
    }
}
```

Possibility1

```
package so;

public class Possibility1 extends Possibility {
    public Possibility1(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Possibility2:

```
package so;

public class Possibility2 extends Possibility {
    public Possibility2(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Possibility3

```
package so;

public class Possibility3 extends Possibility {
    public Possibility3(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would increase the value per every instance that you create of the subclasses.

Comment: Isn't that what you need?

Comment: If you want to count objects (not classes as you said in the question), why not just do the increment in the superclass constructor? It’s simpler and you won’t risk to forget it in one subclass. You can also make the counter private to reduce the risk of unintentional modification from somewhere.

Comment: yup :). Actually I was doing it without super call at first. I've changed it to include inside parent constructor

Comment: Nitpicking, there is no such thing as instantiating a subclass without a super call. Even if it it doesn’t say `super()` in your code, the no-arg super constructor will still be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) which I guess must of OOP devs 
know. I was creating class without calling super and it got stuck(no name parameter was used while I was creating it and was added later to sync with the question).. cheers to new code

Answer (score 0):

The [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) provides a pretty easy way to do this:

```
int numSubTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Possibility.class).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

you must create an integer attribute in Possibility class and and you can get this integer from another class that extends from Possibility, like this:

```
class Possibility{
   public int someInteger;
   //getter 
   public int getSomeInteger(){
       return this.someInteger;
   }
}

class someClass extends Possibility{
   public void someMethode(){
      Possibility possibility = new Possibility("someName");
      //get someInteger 
      possibility.getSomeInteger();
   }
}
```